# Why object is deallocated in a global map

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am working on part of the program where I want to keep a map for a lifetime of the program that will hold an address to an object B.

I have a global map in a file

```
static std::map<A , B*> mapping_;
```

then I have a class and some initialization

```
bool NewItem::initialize() {
    Panel_ = 0;

    if (mapping_[let_] == 0){
      B* tabPanel = new B();
      mapping_[let_] = tabPanel;
    }  

    Panel_ = mapping_[let_];
```

When I come second time in initialize() then it knows about this map so it will skip the if block but members of B object are all deallocated somehow (0xfeeefeee).

I don't think that I am deleting Panel_ anywhere so I don't know how it is possible it is deallocating.

Any ideas what could be happening, or what I am doing wrong, or how can I keep object B in cache until the program closes?

Note: This is just a really small part of the code.

Comment: Give us enough code to replicate the problem.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't think this is possible, the code is quite large. There is no desctructor of B, some member objects of B might have destructors / smart pointers but i guess they shouldn't be called because of map having an address to the object B.

Comment: what kind of object is B? does it got any kind of parent object that is being deallocated, destroyed, erased or re assigned before your program goes back to `bool NewItem::initialize()`? is the initialisation taking place at a most global scope?

Comment: @MateuszW Either you know what code is responsible for the problem or you don't. If you don't, there's a very good chance you aren't showing us the code responsible for the problem. If you do, show us that code. What you've done here is show us a tiny fragment of code with no context (What's `let_`? What's `Panel_`'s constructor look like? Which `Panel_` constructor is being invoked) so we can't even understand what it's doing.

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL B is inherited from wxauinotebook. actually NewItem will get desctructed. Not a most global space.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am not looking for a specific code answer, but some possible hints / what to look for, of what is going on. What I pasted is pretty much a central piece of what I am working on now. Pasting thousands lines of code would not be a very practical. Let is a enum, Panel is B*

Comment: My crystal ball says rule of three violation. But that's just a guess. We need to see the class declarations.

Comment: @MateuszW I imagine from your answer, that you are creating a user defined panel inside the UI of wxauinotebook or at least trying to track one... but it seems you don't have control over the panel itself, so a higher hierarchy object is destroying it and your pointer get lost. You could add a listener that check if it's being destroyed...

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL that is really close. I have a dialog that is populated with tabs. Dialog had a destructor for the tabs but I have commented it out. Dialog itself will get terminated, but since I don't release memory for tabs then I don't know why it would lose the pointer. Basically i want to cache in memory tabs for future, but always initialize fresh dialog.

Comment: @MateuszW In that case, to avoid it being erase by unknow, you could create a copy of the pointer information (the panel) and let the original be destroy...

Comment: Which translation unit contains the definition of `mapping_`?

Comment: @KerrekSB cpp file

Comment: It might be worthwhile to temporarily add code to the B class's destructor that will print out a stack trace -- or alternatively, run the program in a debugger and set a breakpoint in the B class's destructor.  Either way that should get you a stack trace showing where your B objects are being destroyed from, which would clarify the situation.

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL what if the dialog is created on the stack first and then internally it creates tabs inside the dialog on the heap, but then the dialog is destructed. Would that mean that tabPanel_ would be destructed as well? I wouldn't think so

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I will give that a try for sure. But if the destructor doesn't delete the pointer then wouldn't it still matter?

Comment: @MateuszW If the object wasn't supposed to be deleted, and thus the destructor never should have been called.... and yet it is being called... then that is a problem regardless of what the destructor does or doesn't do.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner looks like wxwidgets will destroy children of the dialog meaning the tabs etc. What would be the solution to keep the tabs in the memory? I tried coping the the panel but it gives me a compile error that it can't copy some private members (wxwidgets)

Comment: I've never used wxwidgets so I'm probably not the person to ask, but perhaps you shouldn't try to keep the children in memory.  Instead, allow them to be destroyed and then create new ones later.  If there is some persistent (non-wxwidgets-related) data that you want to be present both before and after, then keep that data around separately, and use it to help recreate the children of the new dialog.

Comment: Is there a way I can make a copy of this tabs and keep it in the memory?

Comment: Dunno, you'll have to read the wxwidgets docs.  As I said, I've never used wxwidgets (ask me about Qt and I would be a lot more helpful :) )